# Calling from a controller to a manager which parameter choose

Tags: c#, parameters

I am creating a method, implemented into a manager (like ReqManager) that is going to be called from a controller ReqController,

the definition could be:

```
public void LockTransDetail(IRow detailRow, DataSet data, string fieldName, bool lockYN)

public void LockTransDetail(IRow detailRow, IDecorator decorator, string fieldName, bool lockYN)
```

so I could perform the first and whe is implemented,

```
public void LockTransDetail(IRow detailRow, DataSet data, string fieldName, bool lockYN)
{
    IDecorator decorator = GetDecorator(data);
    ...... 
}
```

Or the second option is, into the controller do:

```
IDecorator decorator = GetDecorator(data);
```

and then call to the method,

```
ReqControllerInstance.LockTransDetail(detailRow, decorator, fieldName, lockYN)
```

So what is better to pass as parameter the DataSet or de decorator into the created method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understood your question, but if I did, you're asking whether it's better for the Controller to call one monolithic method on the manager (`Manager.DoSomething`), or whether to break it down into several steps (`Manager.ConvertData`, `Manager.GetDecorator`, and then `Manager.DoSomethingWithDecorator`).

This would depend on what these steps are. In the example you bring, I would probably choose the first option. The Controller's role is to orchestrate the workflow - it knows that the current operation needs to be transferred into the `RequestManager`'s responsibility. What it shouldn't do is do the `RequestManager`'s work for it. If you use DataSets are your standard Data Transfer Objects, then that's what you should pass to the Manager. Any further processing should be done in the Manager.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in your last sentence
 If you use DataSets are your standard Data Transfer Objects, then that's what you should pass to the Manager. Any further processing should be done in the Manager.
there is the answer, what I was asking was if is better to call to a manager sending a complete DataSet or a Decorator which is lighter, but I think that is better in order to be independent to send the DataSet

Comment: Are these cross-process calls that require serialization? Because otherwise, "heavy" or "light" are irrelevant, since only a reference is passed.

Answer (score 0):

The second option seems more generic and testable: you class implementation will be decoupled from concrete `data` representation, meaning that you will be able to easily replace `DataSet` with anything else and won't have to change `LockTransDetail()` contract, as it depends on `IDecorator` only.